# Waterfall Logic for SQL Server Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please help me with the following.

I have the data with flags as the following and i need to add 5 additional columns based on those flag columns in a waterfall/Cascade way. I tried to accomplish this with `case` statement but the logic is becoming more confusing.

Here is the sample data and how the end result should look like.

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID          INT,
    Mortality VARCHAR(10),
    Readmission varchar(10),
    EDVisit varchar(10),
    Return_to_OR varchar(10),
    Sepsis varchar(10)
);

DECLARE @endresult AS TABLE
(
    ID          INT,
    Mortality VARCHAR(10),
    Readmission varchar(10),
    EDVisit varchar(10),
    Return_to_OR varchar(10),
    Sepsis varchar(10),
    Indicator1 varchar(15),
    Indicator2 varchar(15),
    Indicator3 varchar(15),
    Indicator4 varchar(15),
    Indicator5 varchar(15)
);


insert into @T VALUES
(1,'Y', 'N', 'Y','Y','Y'), 
(2,'N','Y','N','Y','Y'), 
(3,'N','N','N','Y','Y')

insert into @endresult VALUES
(1,'Y', 'N', 'Y','Y','Y','Mortality','EDVisit','Return_to_OR','Sepsis',null), 
(2,'N','Y','N','Y','Y','Readmission','Return_to_OR','Sepsis',null,null), 
(3,'N','N','N','Y','Y','Return_to_OR','Sepsis',null,null,null)


select * from @T

select * from @endresult
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option which uses a bit of JSON in concert with a conditional aggregation.

On a side note: Assuming you had a typo `EDVisit` vs `ERVisit`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f955a19bdc4d4738563f969f570aff7b)**

```
select A.*
      ,B.*
 From @T A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Indicator1 = max(case when Seq=1 then [Key] end)
                      ,Indicator2 = max(case when Seq=2 then [Key] end)
                      ,Indicator3 = max(case when Seq=3 then [Key] end)
                      ,Indicator4 = max(case when Seq=4 then [Key] end)
                      ,Indicator5 = max(case when Seq=5 then [Key] end)
                From (
                      Select [Key]
                            ,Value
                            ,Seq = row_number() over (order by (select null))
                        From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                        Where [Key] not in ('ID')
                          and Value<>'N'
                     ) B1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot John for the answer. I really don't know JSON, so this is new to me. So the [Key] in the code would be name of the column?

Comment: @Phani  [Key] ... as provided by JSON is the column name.  Take a peek at this version where I remove the conditional aggregation  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=da6e0d4e325f6675d74adb6567ddd40d

Comment: @Phani To be clear, there are more perfomant ways to UNPIVOT your data, but you would have to specify each column.